# Interactively sending commands to java.lang.Process fails

Tags: java, windows, process, cmd

I played around with executing windows processes (cmd.exe in this particular case) out of java and stumbled over a problem.
There is no reaction to the command `net statistics server` (and to no other command).

The examples I saw here on SO created the process with all the argument they needed. But I would like to write directly to the output stream of the process. So how can I do that? What am I doing wrong?

```
public class CmdExecutor
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd");
    pb.directory(new File("/"));
    Process p = null;
    try
    {
      p = pb.start();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    if (p != null)
    {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(p.getInputStream());
      PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());

      boolean commandSent = false;

      while (s.hasNext())
      {
        System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        if (!commandSent)
        {
          out.println("net statistics server");
          commandSent = true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Only output is:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
```

Comment: It works if I `flush` the stream after the `println`. Is there a OutputStream that doesnt buffer and writes directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PrintWriter` will not write data to the `OutputStream` until its buffer is full. You can either flush manually

```
out.flush();
```

or use the constructor that uses *autoflush*

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream(), true);
```

Comment: Thx, also also figured out that I need `flush`... But didn't know about the autoflush :)